# I could not submit a job to the executing node in condor apart from the central manager

Tags: linux, centos, cluster-computing, hpc, condor

I have a condor pool which consist of 4 dedicated machine one is set as a centeral manager, submitting, and executing node  while the other three is set to be executing nodes I used CentOS 5.4 as an OS for all the machines. My problem is when I submitted a job from the central manager it works just on the central manager so when I specify in the JDL file that the job should run in any machine apart from the central manager the job stay in hold and does not run. When I type condor_status all nodes appear. I keep the daemon MASTER, STARTD in the daemon list for the executing nodes. Does any one come across this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information to answer your question, but the first thing to do is to run `condor_q -analyze <jobid>` and see what it tells you.  See the Condor manual [Section 2.6.5: Why is the job not running?](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/latest/2_6Managing_Job.html#sec%3ajob-not-running)

One possible cause is that you're not telling Condor to transfer your input/output files for you, and your nodes have different "filesystem domains", so Condor is unable to find a host which shares a common filesystem with your submit host.